# Why is my list empty after execution?

Tags: r

I managed to fill my `doi_list` but it does not work if I encapsulate the code into a `function`. [From a tutorial](http://www.r-bloggers.com/call-by-reference-in-r/) I've seen I assume that this should be possible but `doi_list` is empty after `get_doi_from_category()` finishes.

```
library(aRxiv)

get_doi_from_category <- function(category, doi_list) {

  arxiv_rec <- arxiv_search(category)
  arxiv_doi_list <- arxiv_rec[13]

  by(arxiv_doi_list, 1:nrow(arxiv_doi_list), 
     function(row) { 
       if(nchar(row) > 0) {
         doi_list <<- c(doi_list, row)
       }
     })
}

doi_list <- list()

get_doi_from_category('cat:stat.ML', doi_list)

for(doi in doi_list) 
{
  print(doi)
} 

get_doi_from_category('cat:stat.CO', doi_list)
get_doi_from_category('cat:stat.ME', doi_list)
get_doi_from_category('cat:stat.TH', doi_list)
```

PS: First day with **R**.

Comment: `arxiv_doi_list` is a single column, no?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Correct.

Comment: no need to use `by` at all.  use `arxiv_rec[,13]` to get a vector. then set `doi_list` to `arxiv_doi_list[nchar(arxiv_doi_list)>0]`.

Comment: also, you should avoid extracting by column number, in general. `arxiv_rec[,"col_name"]` is preferable.

Comment: @MichaelChirico The thing is that I want to append multiple DOIs to `doi_list`. That is why I came up with the `by` solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better way to do what you want in R:

```
categ <- c(CO = "cat:stat.CO", #I'm naming these elements so
           ME = "cat:stat.ME", #  that the corresponding elements
           TH = "cat:stat.TH", #  in the list are named as well.
           ML = "cat:stat.ML") #  Could also just set 'names(doi_list)' to 'categ'.

doi_list <- 
  lapply(categ, function(ctg)
    (doi <- arxiv_search(ctg)$doi)[nchar(doi) > 0])
```

I sort of threw you in the deep end on the last line with in-line assignment of `doi`; a more step-by-step approach would be:

```
lapply(categ, function(ctg){
  arxiv.df <- arxiv_search(ctg)
  doi <- arxiv.df$doi
  doi[nchar(doi) > 0]})
```